# How to use user's timezone in laravel?

Tags: laravel

Let's say, I have `User` model with `text` field named `timezone`.

This field stores string like 'Europe/Moscow' so I can use it like this

```
Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', '2015-10-23 17:64:00', 'Europe/Moscow');
```

Problem:

```
namespace App\Models;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
class Task extends Model {
    public function created_at() {
        $timezone = Auth::user() ? Auth::user()->timezone : config("settings.default_timezone");
        return $this->created_at->setTimezone($timezone);
    }
}
```

Is it good way to do this or I should modify all dates outside of models?

I do not think that it is good way to modify displayed date.

Dates are stored in UTC. Where is the best place to modify stored value for current user?

Answer (score 1):

It's my opinion that storing dates in lots of different timezones in a system is a pretty bad idea. I think you're better off storing all dates and times in UTC (or any other known constant) and then localising the date as and when it's required.

Laravel lets you set the applications timezone through configuration, the default being UTC. Then whenever I've needed to localise a date or time, I've used a user selected or detected locale to modify it.

Comment: You did not read question thoroughly. Dates are stored in UTC. Question is about `where to modify stored value for current user`?

Comment: during fetch or api call